# Turn a matrix $A$ so their elements become linear to each other

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Assume that we have a matrix $A$

```
>> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9]
A =

   1   2   3
   4   5   6
   7   8   9

>>
```

Here we can see that all elements are linear to each other. It's the step size `1`.

But let's assume that I have a matrix that have this. Here we have a normal distributed matrix who mix up the values, so it will be more difficult to see if the matrix A have linear elements to each other.

```
>> A = [1 2 3; 4 5 6; 7 8 9] + randn(3,3)
A =

   1.9732   2.7722   1.0032
   3.0208   4.0953   6.7317
   7.2637   9.3475   8.2641

>>
```

Or we can take this scenario. Here we can see that the center element `1` is linear to all elements, but element number `2` is not linear to anyone. But element `5` is twice the small as `10` and `3` is three times as small as `9`.

```
>> A = [5 2 5; 7 1 10; 72 9 3]
A =

    5    2    5
    7    1    10
   72   9    3

>>
```

**Question:**

Is there any linear method ish, out there that can turn a matrix $A$ so all element, or most of the elements become linear to each other with the step size `1` or other step size that will cause most linearity.

Comment: What does it mean that "elements of a matrix are linear to each other"?

Comment: @obareey Assume that we have a vector [1 2 3], here we can see that the difference between them are linear. But if we have a vector that is [1 2 3 3.5 4.5] now we can see a pattern that they are not linear to each other.

Comment: So you mean the difference between elements are the same?

Comment: If this is the case how is element 1 is "linear to all elements" in your last example?

Comment: @obareey Yes. Image that you have an image and you want all pixels to be linear to each other. Yes, the picture may look weard. But if you map all the pixels so they are linear, the picture may look OK.

Comment: Sorry, this doesn't make any sense to me. I don't understand what "linear to each other" means.